Combining column pairs in a data frame in R
I'm trying to combine genotype data and from a matrix where each row represents one allele i.e., each sample is split into its own row.
I created a data frame (tibble) from the matrix. The data frame has n columns and I want to combine every two columns into one so the final data frame would have n/2 columns.
Example:
Original data frame:
    c1.1  c1.2  c2.1  c2.2  c3.1  c3.2  c4.1  c4.2  c5.1  c5.2
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
 5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
 9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

Resulting data frame:
       c1      c2      c3      c4      c5
1     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
2     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|1
3     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
4     0|1     0|1     0|1     1|1     1|1
5     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
6     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
7     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
8     0|1     0|1     0|1     0|0     0|0
9     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0
10    0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0     0|0

How can I do this?
I tried to use unite from tidyR but it combines all the columns into one.
Feeling kinda frustrated...
Here's the code for generating the example data.
df <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             ncol = 10)


df <- dplyr::as_tibble(df)

samples <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")

names(df) <- paste0(rep(samples, each = 2), c(".1",".2"))


In base R:
split.default(df, sub("[.].*", "", names(df)))|>
   sapply(\(x)do.call(paste, c(x, sep='|')))|>
   data.frame()
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
2  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1
3  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
4  0|1 0|1 0|1 1|1 1|1
5  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
6  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
7  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
8  0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0
9  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
10 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0


 reshape(data.frame(df), names(df), dir = 'long')|>
   aggregate(.~id, paste, collapse='|')|>
   subset(select = -c(time, id))
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
2  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1
3  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
4  0|1 0|1 0|1 1|1 1|1
5  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
6  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
7  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
8  0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0
9  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
10 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0


stack(df)|>
   transform(id = seq(nrow(df)), ind = sub("[.].*","", ind))|>
   aggregate(values~., paste, collapse = '|')|>
   unstack(values~ind)

    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
2  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1
3  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
4  0|1 0|1 0|1 1|1 1|1
5  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
6  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
7  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
8  0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0
9  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
10 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0

Tidyverse:
rowid_to_column(df) %>% 
   pivot_longer(-rowid, names_to = c('name', NA), names_sep = '[.]') %>% 
   pivot_wider(values_fn = ~str_c(., collapse = '|'))

# A tibble: 10 × 6
   rowid c1    c2    c3    c4    c5   
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 2     2 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|1  
 3     3 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 4     4 0|1   0|1   0|1   1|1   1|1  
 5     5 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 6     6 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 7     7 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 8     8 0|1   0|1   0|1   0|0   0|0  
 9     9 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
10    10 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  


In base R, you can use mapply to paste every other column together using a "|" as the separator:
oddcols <- seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2)
# [1] 1 3 5 7 9

new_df <- mapply(paste, df[oddcols], df[oddcols + 1], sep = "|")
colnames(new_df) <- sub("\\..*","", colnames(new_df))

# or alternatively, using `apply`:
df_apply <- t(apply(df, 1, \(x) paste(x[oddcols], x[oddcols + 1], sep = "|")))
colnames(df_apply) <- unique(sub("\\..*","", colnames(new_df)))

#      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5   
# [1,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"
# [2,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|1"
# [3,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"
# [4,] "0|1" "0|1" "0|1" "1|1" "1|1"
# [5,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"
# [6,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"
# [7,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"
# [8,] "0|1" "0|1" "0|1" "0|0" "0|0"
# [9,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"
#[10,] "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0" "0|0"


An approach using unite
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(purrr::map(unique(sub("\\..*", "", colnames(df))), \(x) 
  unite(df[,grep(x, colnames(df))], !!x, sep="|")))
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   c1    c2    c3    c4    c5   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 2 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|1  
 3 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 4 0|1   0|1   0|1   1|1   1|1  
 5 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 6 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 7 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 8 0|1   0|1   0|1   0|0   0|0  
 9 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
10 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0

Note that lapply works instead of purrr::map but is used to stay somewhat close to the tidyverse.

1) map_dfr After splitting the input into a list of pairs paste each pair together.  The tools package comes with R and its file_path_sans_ext when applied to the names removes everything after the dot (.) .
This seems straight-forward with no regular expressions and is pipe friendly observing the left to right idea of pipes with df only appearing at the beginning.
library(purrr)
library(tools)

df %>%
  split.default(file_path_sans_ext(names(.))) %>%
  map_dfr(\(x) paste(x[[1]], x[[2]], sep = "|"))

giving
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   c1    c2    c3    c4    c5   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 2 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|1  
 3 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 4 0|1   0|1   0|1   1|1   1|1  
 5 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 6 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 7 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
 8 0|1   0|1   0|1   0|0   0|0  
 9 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  
10 0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0   0|0  

2) Base R We can translate that to base R - tools comes with R so it is part of base too.  Replace map_dfr with Map and data.frame and make appropriate modifications for the native pipe.
library(tools)

df %>%
  { \(x) split.default(x, file_path_sans_ext(names(x))) }() |>
  Map(f = \(x) paste(x[[1]], x[[2]], sep = "|")) |>
  data.frame()

3) dplyover The dplyover package on github has a convenient across2 which can be used here:
# library(remotes)
# install_github("TimTeaFan/dplyover")

library(dplyr)
library(dplyover)

df %>%
  reframe(across2(ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"), paste, sep = "|",
    .names = "{pre}"))

4) map2_dfr This uses map2_dfr in purrr
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tools)

df %>%
  reframe(map2_dfr(pick(ends_with("1")), pick(ends_with("2")), 
    paste, sep = "|")) %>%
  rename_with(file_path_sans_ext)

Note
Input data:
df <- tibble::tibble(
  c1.1 = numeric(10),
  c1.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  c2.1 = numeric(10),
  c2.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  c3.1 = numeric(10),
  c3.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  c4.1 = rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(3L, 1L, 6L)),
  c4.2 = rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(3L, 1L, 6L)),
  c5.1 = rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(3L, 1L, 6L)),
  c5.2 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
)


Nothing fancy but just base R combo tapply + sub + list2DF
list2DF(
  tapply(
    unclass(df),
    sub("\\..*", "", names(df)),
    \(x) do.call(paste, c(x, sep = "|"))
  )
)

which gives
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
2  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1
3  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
4  0|1 0|1 0|1 1|1 1|1
5  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
6  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
7  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
8  0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0
9  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
10 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0

